# Estructura Arreglo en Java:

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Necesito esta estructura:

> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
>   1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1
>   1 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 1
>   1 2 3 4 4 4 3 2 1
>   1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
>   1 2 3 4 4 4 3 2 1
>   1 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 1
>   1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1
>   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Y tengo este intento de código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner vortex = new Scanner (System.in); 
        System.out.println("Introduce un numero para hacer el patron: ");

        int maxQuant = vortex.nextInt();
        int[][] n = new int[maxQuant*2-1][maxQuant*2-1];

        for(int i=0; i<maxQuant*2-1; i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<maxQuant*2-1;j++) {
                n[i][j]=(int) maxQuant-1;
                System.out.print(n[i][j]+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }



        vortex.close();

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagínate que lo que te piden es esto:

```
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 
4 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 
4 3 2 1 1 1 2 3 4 
4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 
4 3 2 1 1 1 2 3 4 
4 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 
4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

En la que cada número es la distancia que hay con el centro. (En el centro hay distancia 0).

Podrías hacer esto así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner vortex = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce un numero para hacer el patron: ");
    int maxQuant = vortex.nextInt();
    int centro = maxQuant - 1;
    int[][] n = new int[maxQuant * 2 - 1][maxQuant * 2 - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < maxQuant * 2 - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < maxQuant * 2 - 1; j++) {
            n[i][j] = diferenciaCentro(centro, i, j);
            System.out.print(n[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    vortex.close();
}

private static int diferenciaCentro(int centro, int i, int j) {
    return Math.max(Math.abs(centro - i), Math.abs(centro - j));
}
```

Fíjate que he creado una variable centro, que es simplemente la posición del centro. Por ejemplo para n = 5, el centro está en la posición 4.

También he creado una función que me determina la diferencia de una casilla con el centro. Para esta función calculo primero la diferencia del eje X con el centro (utilizo la función de valor absoluto para que no me queden números negativos) y la diferencia con el eje Y. De los dos valores me quedo con el máximo.

Por ejemplo, para (4, 4) obtengo 0, porque es el centro. Para (3, 4) obtengo 1, porque la diferencia del eje X es 1, la diferencia del eje Y es 0, me quedo con el 1. Para (0, 0) la distancia es 4 para los dos ejes, me quedo con el 4.

Una vez tengo eso solo tengo que cambiar esta línea:

```
            // n[i][j] = diferenciaCentro(centro, i, j);
            n[i][j] = maxQuant - diferenciaCentro(centro, i, j);
```

Para invertir los valores y obtener la solución pedida:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 
1 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 4 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 4 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 1 
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Si juegas con las funciones puedes obtener patrones diferentes. Por ejemplo, si cambias max por min obtienes una cruz en vez de una espiral

```
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 
2 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 2 
3 3 3 4 5 4 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 5 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
4 4 4 4 5 4 4 4 4 
3 3 3 4 5 4 3 3 3 
2 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 2 
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
```